# About using window and document in node-jsx and react-engine

Tags: node.js, express, react-ssr

I want to use `.pug` and `.jsx` as express view engine.
I tried it with other modules like `@react-ssr/express`, but they didn't work.
(It seems that my project is based on a open source project that lastly updated a few years ago)
So, I'm using `node-jsx` and `react-engine` now, but these modules wouldn't let me use `window` and `document`.
(Like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNmka.png))
I already tried many solutions through googling like the code below.

```js
const React = require("react");

...

const Index = (props) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // code with document and window
  }
}

module.exports = Index;
```

But blank page was rendered.
I think these modules just render and run my jsx file without any converting to javascript.
Is there no way to use `window` and `document` with `node-jsx` and `react-engine`?
(or please recommend me other modules)

server.js

```js
require("node-jsx").install({ extension: '.jsx', harmony: true });

const renderer = require("react-engine");
const Engine = renderer.server.create();

...

app.set('views', __dirname + "/views");
app.engine('jsx', Engine);
app.set('view engine', "pug");
app.set('view engine', "jsx");
```

index.jsx

```
const React = require("react");

...

const Index = (props) => {
  // code with document and window
}

module.exports = Index;
```